# CRM 2011 - How to install different solutions (features) for a client of our company

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We offer multiple packages with features for our clients with Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Is there a way where we can publish our sollutions with our modifications for certain entities without overwriting the form layout that already existed.

How should we organise our sollutions so there will be no conflicts within the entities in our sollutions nor with the entities that were already modified by our clients where we want to install our sollution?

now we have to modify most entities manualy...

I hope you have some experience you want to share with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We broke up each section of our project into solutions. For example, entities, reports, plugins, etc.

This allowed us to deploy bits and pieces of our project as we went along (moving from dev -> test -> production).

You can't break out pieces of entities (or exclude things like the forms), but you could export the existing solution, make your changes and then re-import (as a manage or unmanaged).

There's a really good diagram [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx) under "Conflict Resolution".

Comment: Thanks man, i think that article will help me a lot. But what if we have multiple projects. Each client can choose his edition of our project. Like 'starter' , 'pro' or 'gold' for example. These sollutions all effect the contact entity. Is it possible to install the starter, and then later install the pro and maybe also the gold? Without having the starter components included in the pro and gold edition?

Comment: Np! Yes you can have different solutions do different things. In the same link above you're going to want to go to the section "Unmanaged and Managed Solutions". Essentially managed and unmanaged solutions allow you to control what happens with your solutions. For example: Disabling the ability to edit your entities, or how items are installed or uninstalled.

Quote from article: "Managed solutions can also be layered on top of other managed solutions." 

So as the client wants more upgrades you can install the solutions accordingly.

Comment: Forgot to add, if the client wants to downgrade you can uninstall that version (lets say gold) of the solution (as long as it's managed).